# Referencing a php function inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to display a dynamic dropdown menu that withdraws data from mysql, but having trouble with referencing my php function inside javascript.

Here is my php function:

```
function query(){
  $myData = mysqli_query(dbconnect1(), "select time from time");

  while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($myData)){
    echo '<option value="' . $record['time'] . ' ">' .$record['time'] . '"</option>';
  }
}
```

And here is the js where I want to reference it:

```
var $modal = $( '<div class="rm-modal"><div class="rm-thumb" <h5>' + title + '</h5><span class="rm-close-modal">x</span></div>' );
```

The problem is, I cannot reference the php query in there.

I know it is a problem referencing php inside javascript, but could someone come up with alternative solution which is easy to understand (since I'm a newbie)?

Comment: You can use ajax. Demo : http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-countries-and-states/

Comment: Any idea how to do that?